# CodeIgniter MySQL escaping

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, pdo

I'm running the following query:

```
INSERT INTO deal (`site_id`, `status`, `slug`, `title`, `description`, `condition`, `sale_price`, `shipping`, `deal_url`, `buy_url`, `start`, `added`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `site_id` = ?,`status` = ?,`slug` = ?,`title` = ?,`description` = ?,`condition` = ?,`sale_price` = ?,`shipping` = ?,`deal_url` = ?,`buy_url` = ?,`start` = ?
```

Built by this code:

```
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO
            deal
                (`'.implode('`, `', array_keys($insert)).'`, `added`)
            VALUES
                ('.implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($insertValues), '?')).', NOW())
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            '.implode(',', array_keys($update)), array_merge($insertValues, array_values($update)));
```

The issue with this is that my query isn't properly escaping....

```
INSERT INTO deal (`site_id`, `status`, `slug`, `title`, `description`, `condition`, `sale_price`, `shipping`, `deal_url`, `buy_url`, `start`, `added`) VALUES ('2', 1, http://www.woot.com/sale/sony-dash-personal-internet-viewer-7, 'Sony Dash Personal Internet Viewer', 'Finally, someone made me my own, personal internet!', 'New', '69.99', $5 shipping, http://www.woot.com/sale/sony-dash-personal-internet-viewer-7, , 1305867600, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `site_id` = '2',`status` = 1,`slug` = http://www.woot.com/sale/sony-dash-personal-internet-viewer-7,`title` = 'Sony Dash Personal Internet Viewer',`description` = 'Finally, someone made me my own, personal internet!',`condition` = 'New',`sale_price` = '69.99',`shipping` = $5 shipping,`deal_url` = http://www.woot.com/sale/sony-dash-personal-internet-viewer-7,`buy_url` = ,`start` = 1305867600
```

I have XSS filtering setup.... am I missing something?

Comment: XSS and sql injections are different sort of vulnerabilities and should be processed in different ways.

Comment: The point of a PDO is usually that queries are abstracted, and therefore don't require escaping since they don't require building. I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but I recommend that you confirm that there isn't a more standard way of doing this insert.

Comment: @Matchu They have something called ActiveRecord (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), but that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` doesn't have an equivalent function, so you'd be stuck doing a `SELECT` first to see if the data exists

Answer (score 0):

Odd. What's the database definition? The only thing I can think of is that the DB layer is concluding that some of those columns don't need escaping.